# How can I tell if elements generate or $F_n$ or $F_n \times F_n$?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $F_n$ be the free group on the letters $x_1,...,x_n$.  Given a set of elements $\{ w_1,...,w_m \} \subset F_n$ how can I tell if they generate $F_n$? Are there nice necessary/sufficient conditions?

Similarly I would like to be able to tell if a finite setoff elements in $F_n \times F_n$ generate the whole group?  Is there an algorithmic way to do this?

Comment: I am not an expert, but this strikes me as asking for so much that it may be undecidable... E.g., in general, the group isomorphism problem (with groups presented by generators and relations) is undecidable... probably google-able.

Comment: This is decidable for $F_n$ and undecidable for $F_n\times F_n$. The former because every finitely-generated subgroup of $F_n$ is quasiconvex, the latter is because of Mikhailova's construction.

Comment: Although the problem is undecidable in general for $F_n \times F_n$, it is semi-decidable in the sense that if the given elements do generate the whole group then you can prove that they do. The Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration procedure is probably the most efficient way to do that in practice.

Comment: To summarize the negative solution for $F_2\times F_2$: for $F_2=\langle x,y\rangle$, a presentation $\langle x,y\mid r_1,\dots,r_n\rangle$ defines the trivial group iff $\{(x,x),(y,y),(1,r_1),\dots,(1,r_n)\}$ generates $F_2\times F_2$ (straightforward verification). Hence an algorithm for whether a finite subset generates $F_2\times F_2$ would yield an algorithm to solve the triviality problem, which is known not to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are several algorithms for deciding if a finite set of elements $x_1,...,x_k$ generates the free group $F=F(y_1,...,y_n)$. Here is one (another algorithm I know is based on quasiconvexity):

For each generator $y_i$ of $F$ run two algorithms in parallel:

A. Enumerate all words $w=w(x_1,...,x_k)$ in the elements $x_1,...,x_k$, rewritten as reduced words in $y_1,...y_n$, and for each  word check if $w$ equals $y_i$. If for some $w$ it is, then proceed to the next generator $y_{i+1}$. If for all $y_i$'s you conclude that such $w=w_i$ exists, then $x_1,...,x_k$ generate $F$. (This is the semidecidability Derek referred to: It works whenever the ambient group has solvable word problem, you do  not need to assume that the group is free. For instance, $F_n\times F_n$ has solvable word problem, for obvious reason.)

B. For each permutation group $S_N$ enumerate all homomorphisms $\phi: F\to S_N$ and for each  $\phi$ check if $\phi(y_i)$ belongs to the subgroup generated by $\phi(x_1),...,\phi(y_k)$. If for some $\phi$ it does not, then you are done: The elements $x_1,...,x_k$ do not generate $F$.

The point is that each free group $F$ is LERF: For every finitely generated subgroup $H<F$ and $y\in F \setminus H$ there exists a homomorphism $\phi: F\to S_N$ such that  $\phi(y)\notin \phi(H)$. Hence, if $H=<x_1,...,x_k>$ is a proper subgroup of $F$ then some free generator $y_i$ is not in $H$. Hence, the above algorithm will eventually prove it.

2. As for $F_n\times F_n$, there exist a family of finitely-generated normal subgroups $K< G=F_n\times F_n$ such that for the finitely-presented groups $Q=G/K$ it is undecidable if such a group group is trivial or not. (This is [Mikhailova's construction](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/subgroups-of-the-direct-product-of-two-free-groups/)). Therefore, it is undecidable if the generators of $K$ generate $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer to your question regarding $F_n$.

Nielsen's 1921 paper "On Calculation with non-commutative factors and its applications to group theory" gives an algorithmic answer to a special case of your question, namely when $w_1,...,w_m$ is a free basis of $F_n$. The modern approach to Nielsen's algorithm uses Stallings fold sequences, and furthermore that approach easily generates to an algorithm for deciding when $w_1,...,w_m$ generates $F_n$. The success of this algorithm is perhaps the best necessary and sufficient condition that I know.

The algorithm is topological in nature and that's the easiest way to describe it, although since it is entirely about finite graphs it is easily programmable.

Let $R_n$ be the rose graph with edges labelled $x_1,...,x_m$, hence $\pi_1(R_n)$ is identified with $F_n$.

Similarly let $R_m$ be the rose graph with edges labelled by abstract symbols $W_1,...,W_m$, hence $\pi_1(R_m)$ is identified with $F_m$. Here I am thinking of $W_i$ as an abstract symbol representing the word $w_i \in F_n$.

Let $f : R_m \to R_n$ the map which takes vertex to vertex and takes the edge of $R_m$ labelled $W_i$ to the edge path in $R_n$ labelled by letters of the word $w_i$.

Your question is equivalent to the following question: How can I tell that the induced map $f_* : \pi_1(R_m) \to \pi_1(R_n)$ is surjective?

The answer is:

1. Construct a Stallings fold factorization of the map $f$:
   $$R_m = G_0 \xrightarrow{f_1} G_1 \xrightarrow{f_2} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_K} G_K \xrightarrow{h} R_n
   $$
   I'll say what this is in a minute, but suffice it for the moment to say that this is a sequence of finite connected graphs and maps which is easily calculated from the original map $f : R_m \to R_n$, the final map $h : G_K \to R_n$ is a local injection, and the induced fundamental group homomorphisms of these two maps have the same image in $\pi_1(R_n)=F_n$, that is, $\text{image}(f_*)=\text{image}(h_*)$.
2. Check whether the final map $h : G_K \to R_n$ is a homeomorphism. If so then $\text{image}(f_*) = \pi_1(R_n)=F_n$ and hence $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ generates $F_n$. If not then $\text{image}(f_*)$ is a proper subgroup of $F_n$ and hence $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ does not generate $F_n$.

Next let me describe Step 1, how to construct the Stallings fold factorization of $f$.

The word $w_i$ is a reduced word in the generators $x_1,..,x_m$ and their inverses. Let $L_i$ be the length of $w_i$. Subdivide the edge of $R_m$ labelled $W_i$ into $L_i$ oriented, labelled edgelets, where an edgelet is labelled $x_i$ if and only if the corresponding letter of $w_i$ is $x_i$ or $x_i^{-1}$, the orientation points forward if that letter is $x_i$, and backwards if that letter is $x_i^{-1}$.

The Stallings fold sequence is constructed inductively, starting from 
$$R_m = G_0 \xrightarrow{f = h_0} R_n
$$
In the inductive step, given
$$R_m = G_0 \xrightarrow{f_1} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_k} G_k \xrightarrow{h_k} R_n
$$
one asks whether $h_k$ is a local injection. If so, the induction is complete. If not, then there are two oriented edgelets $e,e' \subset G_k$ with the same label and with the same initial or same terminal vertex. One may then factor $h_k : G_k \to R_n$ as
$$G_k \xrightarrow{f_{k+1}} G_{k+1} \xrightarrow{h_{k+1}} R_n
$$
where $f_{k+1}$ identifies $e$ and $e'$. Since $G_{k+1}$ has one fewer edgelet than $G_k$, the induction must stop. It's easy to see that $(f_k)_*$ and $(f_{k+1})_*$ have the same image, hence when the induction stops the maps $f_*$ and $h_*$ have the same image.

Finally let me justify Step 2. Since $h : G_K \to R_n$ is locally injective, it follows from simple topological arguments that there exists a connected covering map $\tilde h : \tilde G \to R_n$ and an embedding $i : G_K \hookrightarrow \tilde G$ such that $h = \tilde h \circ i$. This implies that $h_*$ fails to be surjective if and only if one of the following holds: the covering map $\tilde h$ has degree $d \ge 2$, or $\tilde h$ has degree $d=1$ and $\tilde G$ is a proper subgraph of $G_K$; equivalently, $h$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful to see spelled out!